# Lemma 2.5.5 Boas, Entire functions

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, roots

I'm reading Boas, Entire functions, but I don't understand lemma 2.5.5, which states that $\sum_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{r_{n}^{\alpha}}$ and the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{-\alpha -1}n(t)dt$ converge or diverge together. In particular I don't understand the notation $\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{-\alpha}dn(t)$, what is $dn(t)$ ?

Here if $\{z_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are the zeros of an entire function $f$, then $r_{n} = |z_{n}|$, $\alpha $ is the exponent of convergence of the zeros and $n(t)$ is the number of zeros in $\overline{D(0,t)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume there are infinitely many zeroes and $|z_n|\uparrow \infty$. Then
$\int_{|z_n|}^{|z_{n+1}|}t^{-\alpha-1}n(t)\mathrm dt=-(n+1)\frac 1\alpha (|z_{n+1}|^{-\alpha}-|z_{n}|^{-\alpha})$  and we conclude summing by parts.

The notation $\int_0^\infty t^{—\alpha}\mathrm dn(t)$ is the Stieljes integral associated to the non-decreasing function $t\mapsto n(t)$.

Comment: @WimC Of course! Thank you.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Why is there that factor $-(n+1)$ ?

Comment: Because $n(t)=n+1$ on $(|z_n|,|z_{n+1}|]$.

Answer (score 2):

Informally it means $ n'(t) dt$.  However, since $n$ is a step function it is not differentiable.  It has to be interpreted in a distributional sense: $$dn(t) = \sum_n \delta_{r_n}(t)dt$$ where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac delta distribution at $x$.  Note that the $r_n$ are the locations where $n$ steps up by one (or more than one if some $r_n$ are equal).  This Dirac distribution is such that $$\int_0^{\infty}f(t)\delta_x(t)dt=f(x)$$ for continuous functions $f$.